# TFS 2018 Wiki HTML Video not displaying embedded video

Tags: tfs, html5-video

I'm using VSTFS 2018 Version 16.131.28226.3

When I edit a wiki page on one of my repositories and drag and drop a video on the page, it successfully adds the video to the .attachments directory and I add this to the 'src' property of the video but no video is ever displayed.  The examples on Microsoft's tutorials on TFS surrounding adding html video to a wiki all involve external video sources.

Can anyone confirm what I'm trying to do actually works?

```
<video  width=400 controls>
    <source src=".attachments/InvoiceSearch0001-2634-dd51e9fa-ce57-4b0f-a5d6-c9450a9e6036.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: is the relative path you have in the `src` correct? if you add that to the page URL does the video load or 404? If you check the browser console or networking trace are you finding the file? Does the video correctly play in the browser when referenced directly (might be a codec issue)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by doing the following:

1. the format I was using above doesn't work
2. Go to [Microsoft Docs for TFS Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#html-tag-support-in-wiki-pages) and follow the format they show for adding HTML video or just refer to example below.
3. For some reason I can't use a relative path like I could for an image.

How to get path of video:

1. Go to the repository of your wiki and browse the video file within the .attachments folder.  You'll see a little link for "Click to download file to your computer".
2. Right click on the link and copy link.
3. Paste this link replacing the src below

Example shown from MS docs:

```
<video src="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7247/7c8ddc1a-348b-4ba9-ab61-51fded6e7247/vstswiki_high.mp4" width=400 controls>
```